# Bring text (message) down when triggering an object?

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, transform

I'm doing an interactive map of a library an I wanted so that when the player came in contact and triggered and invisible object around the map, a text displaying a message would come down to his view and then he could press enter and it would go back up, when I try to run the code my console says "cannot modify the return value of 'Transform.position' because it is not a variable". Maybe it has to do with the fact that text is 'RectTranform' and not Transform, I don't know

Here is the triggering code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
//I misspelled collision but that doesn't matter
public class collsiion : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter(){
         FindObjectOfType<messageToggle>().goingdown();
    }
     
}
```

And here is the message moving code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class messageToggle : MonoBehaviour
{
   public RectTransform _message;

   public bool gru = false;

   public float brumium = 50f;
   public void goingdown(){
        _message.posY =- brumium;
        gru = true;
   }
   void Update()
    {
        if(gru == true){
            if(Input.GetKey("f")){
                //by the way does anyone know how to put Enter key as an input
                _message.position.y =+ brumium;
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Transform.position is a *property* and upon access, a copy is returned as it's a struct. To avoid an error being thrown, you need to reassign the position vector:

```
_message.position = new Vector3(_message.position.x, _message.position.y + brumium, _message.position.z);
```

Alternatively, you can Translate it :(https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html)

Comment: Thanks, it worked and the due was tomorrow so you saved me